# How do I suppress the list of acronyms

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I am using the `acronym` package to handle my acronyms. To use the package, I have to define all the acronyms within a `\begin{acronym} ... \end{acronym}`. This generates a listing of acronyms that I want to exclude from my final output. Is there a way to exclude these pages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`acronym` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/acronym) provides an option `nolist` that does not write a list of acronyms:

```
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}% http://ctan.org/pkg/acronym
```

Comment: Thanks---that is much better than trying to hide the box by shrinking it down to 0 height or something...