# Omit list of acronyms

Tags: table-of-contents, acronyms

I have a text which includes some acronyms `\ac{ABC}`, but I want to omit the list of acronyms from my final document. As [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29427/how-do-i-suppress-the-list-of-acronyms) suggests, I tried:

```
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
```

but the title "List of Acronyms" still shows up on its own page. How can I completely omit it?

The alternative would be to comment out the package and find a way to deal with the `\ac{}` tags without removing them.

Comment: You could use `\def\ac#1{\ignorespaces}`. However, the `nolist` option should work. Perhaps you need to remove your `aux` files or run `pdflatex` or `latex` a few more times. I don't know the mechanism `acronym` uses well enough to say for sure whether or not this will have any impact.

Comment: Tried removing `aux` files and re-running `pdfLaTeX`, problem persists. `\def\ac#1{\ignorespaces}` removes the acronyms, but I need to keep them, just not have pdflatex choke on the `\ac{}` bits without the package defined.

Comment: My problem is coming from my acronyms file `acronyms.tex`, which I `\include` in my main document, and which begins with an unnumbered section, the section name is being printed but not the list because of the `nolist` option...

Comment: ok... I suppose you could use `\includeonly` then.

Comment: I think \includeonly works only in the preamble, but I need to insert after document start.

Comment: How about enclosing the `\include` in `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` and adding `\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}`after `\begingroup`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From **acronym**'s documentation:

> If one does not want an acronym list to be produced at all, acronyms can be 
>   defined directly thanks to the two commands
>
> `\newacro{⟨acronym⟩}[⟨short name⟩]{⟨full name⟩}`
>      `\acrodef{⟨acronym⟩}[⟨short name⟩]{⟨full name⟩}`
>
> the difference between the two consisting in the fact that the latter makes the 
>   acronym deﬁnition stored in the `.aux` ﬁle. Therefore, the acronym becomes available from start-up in the next run.

Answer (score 3):

The package `acronym` doesn't automatically produce a title for the list of acronyms. If you want a title, you have to set it yourself. Not setting a title and using

```
\usepackage[nolist]{acronym}
```

in the preamble shouldn't be printing anything.

With the environment

```
\begin{acronym}[aligator]
    \acro{abs}[\textsc{abs}]{Acrylonitrile Butadiene Styrene}
    \acro{ac}[\textsc{ac}]{Acrylic}
\end{acronym}
```

one gets a list of acronyms that is defined as a `description` type list. In essence, it's not much different (of course, it's much different, otherwise we wouldn't need the package) from saying

```
\begin{description}[aligator]
    \item[\textsc{abs}]{Acrylonitrile Butadiene Styrene}
    \item[\textsc{ac}]{Acrylic}
\end{description}
```