# Don't display List Of Acronyms page

Tags: acronyms, article

I am writing a paper and I would like to use the `acronym` package to deal with correct placement of acronyms/meanings. However, I don't want to be forced to present a section with the acronyms such as `\section*{Acronyms}`, since it is a paper, not a report, book, etc. Is it possible to use `acronym` without printing the acronyms list? Below a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}

\title{My Paper Title}
\author{J. Lima Filho}
\date{April 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{OPV}{Organic Photovoltaic}
\end{acronym}

\section{Introduction}
One important field of research is on \acp{OPV} due to their unique features, such as low cost and ease of fabrication.

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for the nice MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be a duplicate of [How do I suppress the list of acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29427) which I found by searching for `"acronym suppress list of"`. Turns out that the `acronym`  package has a **`nolist` option**, see below.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[printonlyused, nolist]{acronym} % <-- ADDED "nolist"

\title{My Paper Title}
\author{J. Lima Filho}
\date{April 2022}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Acronyms}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{OPV}{Organic Photovoltaic}
\end{acronym}

\section{Introduction}
One important field of research is on \acp{OPV} due to their unique features, such as low cost and ease of fabrication.

\end{document}
```

Also related is [Omit list of acronyms](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38025).

Comment: Thank you! I agree as being a duplicate.